# Unable to pass value into params for rails form_tag form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form_tag form (new.html.erb) which looks like this:

```html
<% provide(:title, "Initiate a Transaction") %>
<h1>New Transaction</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_tag '/fund_orders' do %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :investment_type, "Transaction Type" %>
        <%= select_tag :investment_type, options_from_collection_for_select(@investment_type, 'id', 'transaction_type'), prompt: "--Select--" %>
      </div>
      <% @orders.each_with_index do |fund_order, index| %>
        <% fieldname = 'fund_orders' + '[' + index.to_s + ']' %>
        <%= fields_for fieldname, fund_order do |f| %>
          <%= render 'fund_order_details', fund_order: f %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Initiate Transaction", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create multiple new transactions through this form. The piece of code within the `@orders.each_with_index` 
block is the part that takes care of the form fields for transactions. However - you will notice that I have a select_tag at the top. After submitting the form - the params are populated with the data for each @order (as i see in the development console), but it doesn't contain `params[:investment_type]`. What is going wrong here?

I tried removing the `@orders.each_with_index` block completely and even then `params[:investment_type]` doesn't get passed. Thoughts?

**Update:** 
I've updated the view on top. Also - this the `fund_order_details` partial that gets called from the view:

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
    <%= fund_order.label :fund_house, "Fund House" %>
    <%= fund_order.collection_select(:fund_house, FundHouse.where(real_fund_house: true), :id, :fund_house,
                            {:prompt => "--Select--", :class => "fund_house"},
                            {:data => {:remote => true,
                                        :url => url_for(controller: "fund_orders",
                                                        action: "update_fundnames")
                                        }})%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= fund_order.label :fund, "Fund Name" %>
    <%= fund_order.collection_select(:fund, MutualFund.none, :id, :fund_name,
                              {:prompt => "--Select--", :class => "fund_name"})%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= fund_order.label :amount %>
    <%= fund_order.number_field(:amount, in: 1000..99999, step: 500) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= fund_order.label :start_date, "Starting date" %>
    <%= fund_order.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "DD/MM/YYYY", required: true  %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

@taryn-east - here is what the HTML looks like.

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1>New Transaction</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form action="/fund_orders/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="HcHWLUTlLpMLMhgtdcFVumLvvD1DqmTdLvmr+Imm3Thlc+nZr0BqYjm30Gq9b+stemaylbIN83JpbEnL0cy3dg==">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="investment_type">Transaction Type</label>
        <select name="investment_type" id="investment_type" disabled="disabled"><option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1">Purchase</option>
<option value="2">Redeem</option>
<option value="3">SIP</option>
<option value="4">SWP</option>
<option value="5">STP</option>
<option value="6">Switch</option></select>
      </div>
        
          <fieldset style="display: block;">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_0_fund_house">Fund House</label>
    <select data-remote="true" data-url="/update_fundnames" name="fund_orders[0][fund_house]" id="fund_orders_0_fund_house"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">ICICI</option>
<option value="2">SBI</option>
<option value="3">Axis</option>
<option value="4">HDFC</option>
<option value="5">Reliance</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_0_fund">Fund Name</label>
    <select name="fund_orders[0][fund]" id="fund_orders_0_fund"><option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_0_amount">Amount</label>
    <input step="500" min="1000" max="99999" type="number" name="fund_orders[0][amount]" id="fund_orders_0_amount">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_0_start_date">Starting date</label>
    <input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" type="text" name="fund_orders[0][start_date]" id="fund_orders_0_start_date">
  </div>
</fieldset>
        
          <fieldset style="display: none;">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_1_fund_house">Fund House</label>
    <select data-remote="true" data-url="/update_fundnames" name="fund_orders[1][fund_house]" id="fund_orders_1_fund_house"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">ICICI</option>
<option value="2">SBI</option>
<option value="3">Axis</option>
<option value="4">HDFC</option>
<option value="5">Reliance</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_1_fund">Fund Name</label>
    <select name="fund_orders[1][fund]" id="fund_orders_1_fund"><option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_1_amount">Amount</label>
    <input step="500" min="1000" max="99999" type="number" name="fund_orders[1][amount]" id="fund_orders_1_amount">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fund_orders_1_start_date">Starting date</label>
    <input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" type="text" name="fund_orders[1][start_date]" id="fund_orders_1_start_date">
  </div>
</fieldset>
      <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Initiate Transaction" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
</form>  </div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

I had simplified the view - but have added the complete HTML now.

Also - here are the parameters being passed to the server logs:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HcHWLUTlLpMLMhgtdcFVumLvvD1DqmTdLvmr+Imm3Thlc+nZr0BqYjm30Gq9b+stemaylbIN83JpbEnL0cy3dg==", "fund_orders"=>{"0"=>{"fund_house"=>"", "fund"=>"", "amount"=>"", "start_date"=>"10/08/2016"}, "1"=>{"fund_house"=>"", "fund"=>"", "amount"=>"", "start_date"=>"10/08/2016"}}, "commit"=>"Initiate Transaction"}
```

For now - I'm only trying to setup the view properly and pass all the params i need from the view to the controller. I don't have any strong params require settings in the controller yet. Please see if this is enough details. I've also edited the view .html.erb code above to show what it looks like in entirety.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question and add a few things that might help us figure out what's going wrong for you? The best thing would be for you to look in your sever logs and give us as example of the params that are coming through. Also sometimes there is an error after that (eg "Unpermitted params") - have you checked that the field is in your `permit/require` in your controller? It also might be useful if you can show us the html that is generated for your form... we can start with that and see how it goes :)

Comment: @TarynEast - I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aha, the html has the clue:

```
<select name="investment_type" id="investment_type" disabled="disabled">
```

Your browser won't send through any values from a disabled field... so... now you need to figure out why that field is disabled.

Comment: Phew! I was setting the field to disabled through JS post selection. I have too few reputation points to upvote the answer - but this worked like a charm :) ... Thanks Taryn.